# Help in this proof in basic abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't have much experience in this subject, I need help:

[image]

I didn't understand the red part and why $|\sigma|$ is the least $m$.

Could anyone help me? any clarification is very welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint : For example Let g=(12)(345) so when g^n=1 then both of (12)^n=1 and (345)^n=1 please see (12)(345)=(345)(12)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since the cycles are disjoint, then they commute with each other.

So if we let $\tau = \sigma_1 \cdot \sigma_2 \cdot \cdot \cdot \sigma_n$, what is the order of $\tau$?

Well, if we compose $\tau$ with itself $m$ times, we get the following after commuting the disjoint $\sigma$'s:

$$\tau^m = \sigma_1^m \cdot \sigma_2^m \cdot \cdot \cdot \sigma_n^m$$

Remember that, if the order of $\tau$ is $m$, then that means that $m$ is the smallest number such that $\tau^m = id$.  Well, for this to happen, $m$ must also satisfy $\sigma_i^m = id$ for all $i$.  Therefore, $m$ must be the least common multiple of the orders of each $\sigma_i$.